# logic Apps : What are possible reason that an new-email-trigger does not fire or failed?

Tags: email, triggers, azure-logic-apps

The office365 trigger when new -email arrives (V3) is my logic Appp trigger condition.

The workflow does following:

1. Triggered on incomnig e-mails
2. check if sender  is an AD User, if not send to a special Mailaddress
3. analyse the subject and put informations gother in new mailboydies and
   distribute the mail to other mailboxes

I have seen a few cases I don' t understand, what it is the reason for that.

1. I got a trigger sicceeded but the trigger doe not fired Why?

   [image]

   image1: trigger History

   [image: last not fired triger]
   image 2: not Fired Triggers
   Screenshot shows succeeded triggers but not fired to start a run.
   In this time spawn there was no email in the inbox.
2. I got a trigger failed ( i cannot reconstruct  which mail could the reason).

   [image: failed Trigger]
   image3: failed Trigger
   for this case I can say nothing i  found no e-mail at this time,
   but it is possible that there was through Dectivation/Activation of logic app
   old not readed mails ttries to trigger.
   it was the first trigger after creation of this Logic app for testing
   (copied from other subscription).

Can someone say me possible reasons for this 2 situations?

Comment: Could you please share the details steps of you logic app ? And could you please share a screenshot of the failure running instance details ?

Answer (score 1):

A status of skipped just indicates that the nothing new was found to fire the logic. Because the trigger will do check operation every once in a while even though the mailbox do not receive new email.

I think you do not need to worry about the records under "**Trigger history**". You just need to check the records under "**Runs history**". The records under "**Runs history**" can give a more intuitive picture of what's your logic app going on.

Comment: It  would estimate risk, if a trigger not fired so could be there are real email which will not proccessed. For that I need potential issues for Not Firing the Trigger after Trigger Succeeded.  
So  i will understand the the trigger reasons for. e.g.  run triggers could execute again if moving processed emails to inbox  with unread state.
So I assume on the triggers fired / not fired  there can happened simillar things too.

Comment: Hi @ingo_ww Sorry for delay reply. For your concern, it relates to the backend logic of logic app trigger. I think you'd better [ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) azure support team for help about this question.

Comment: HI @Hury Shen  Should I delete this post? I think I get here no answer. 
Sorry but your answer I could not accept your because you wrote gneneral known answer.